# A guess about first eigenfunction and scalar curvature on Riemannian 2-sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, eigenfunctions

For any Riemannian 2-sphere $(S^2,g)$, $R$ is its scalar curvature, and $R_A$ is the average value of $R$. $f$ is the first eigenfunction of Laplacian. Then I guess that for
$$
\int_{S^2} (R-R_A) f^2 \ge 0
~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~
\int_{S^2} (R-R_A) |\nabla f|^2 \ge 0
$$
at least one of them is right.

Of course, I don't know how to prove it. Maybe it's not easy to prove either. If so, I want to know, what books or papers should I read if I want to study this kind of problem ?

Comment: The circle-invariant case is naturally a lot more restrictive, but Martin Engman had a paper or two about this case around 2000 that might be of interest? (Wasn't able to find citations after a bit of searching, unfortunately....)

Comment: I assume that $g$ is an arbitrary smooth metric on $S^2$, right? Is there any reason you believe this should be true?

Comment: @JackT  Yes, it is smooth metric.  this is the derivative of first eigenvalue under normalized ricci flow which deform $S^2,g$ to round sphere.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  I think one of them is  SHARP BOUNDS FOR EIGENVALUES AND MULTIPLICITIES ON SURFACES OF REVOLUTION [https://msp.org/pjm/1998/186-1/pjm-v186-n1-p03-s.pdf  ].  My hard analysis skills are terrible,   I think I should take my time. Thanks very much.